# ASP.NET Development Server Failed to start on port

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I have created a website in Visual studio 2005. When i run it shows its following two error.
[image]

[image]

I have googled it got lost of suggestions but not working.I had Set specific port and opened that in firewall but getting same error. And Other projects in Visual Studio 2010 working fine.

Comment: Removed iis tag, as it has nothing to do with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that port is not in use:
Open command prompt and type netstat -a

If it is in use, find what is using it.

Run VS as admin.

Also check that IIS is not bound to that port and check the user tray to see if VS is using the local iis webserver on that port. Basically look for a little yellow icon that kind of looks like a web page, right click and click close.

Try restarting your PC and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this below command and run as administrator

```
net stop hns && net start hns
```

worked for me..!!